# How to set base URL on the installation of Craft CMS on server

Tags: installation

I am a beginner. I just install it on a server and also on localhost. But facing the same problem.
I set it http://www.example.com/ but I go to this URL it shows me the directory but when I go to http://www.example.com/web it goes to the default template.
I want to access default template on http://www.example.com

Answer (score 1):

Create a new web server to host your Craft project. Its document root should point to your public HTML folder. If you’re using Craft’s Composer starter project, then it is the web/ directory by default, but it can be renamed to anything you want as long as your web server is configured to point to it.

If your web host already has a public HTML folder setup to for you that you cannot rename, then you can just copy the contents of Craft’s web folder to it and use your host’s default public HTML folder.

Comment: please explain it to me in detail...